# Loop on Codeigniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, loops

I have a table that contains an unknown number of elements. These represent business sectors.

```
Array ([0] => 1 [1] => 3 [2] => 6 [3] => 7)
```

In this case this activity is linked to topics 1, 3, 6 and 7.

I Have some members who have indicated their fields of interest when they register. Interest fields correspond to sectors of activities.

When a new activity is announced, I would like to send an email to members who have checked at least one common interest with the activity. But I have no idea how to retrieve the email of all those members().

In the database the interests of members is stored like this: `246`
The first member would be interested in sectors 2, 4 and 6.

[image]

I know how to do if there is only one business sector for the activity (example if value = 1).

```
function readMemberInterest($value) {
    $datas = $this->db->select("email")
                ->from($this->table)
                ->like('interet',$value,'both');

                  return $datas;

}
```

But I do not know where and how to place my LOOP and my OR (is for example value = Array ([0] => 1 [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqQgN.jpg) => 3 [2] => 6 [3] => 7) ).

**Briefly, I want to retrieve email members who have at least one common interest with activity. Any tips?**

I hope to be clear, my English is not so great ...
Thanks

Comment: Can you post your table structure ?

Comment: Ok, thanks alot I will look for where_in on the Internet! :)

Comment: I can give live help if you can connect to me via teamviewer? I can edit the query live.

Comment: I added the table structure of the interest of the members

Comment: Do you store user id in the interest table? if yes compare the id on interest table and id in user table.

Comment: And your query is odd too, if not wrong :)

Comment: Do you give up? :D

Comment: ;) No I don't... i'm doing more research ... :S

Comment: Lets move to chat. Or just connect via teamviewer, i'm gonna fix your issue :p

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108563/discussion-between-hendra-nucleo-and-veronique).

Comment: Im finish, whre are you?